# unable to publish clickonce application on aws ec2 through ftp in load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp, clickonce, amazon-elb

Recently I installed SSL using ZeroSSL on my website and for doing that I had to deploy Load Balancer for my EC2 instance (IIS 10). I was initially using ftp to directly publish my ClickOnce application. But now I am not able to publish my application. It shows:

> Failed to connect to 'ftp://website/folder' with the following error: Unable to create the Web site 'ftp://website/folder'. The server unexpectedly closed connection.

On the other hand I am able to connect via `telnet` to the server. But I am unable to connect via file explorer, it shows connection timed out.

Is it possible to do ftp publish through aws Load Balancer? If yes then, please point me in correct direction. And if no, what are other options?

Thanks a lot for taking time to answer and read my question!

PS. Please do let me know if you want any other details.

Comment: Which load balancer?

Comment: Application Load Balancer, Internet Facing

Comment: ALB is for http, not ftp. Try with network load balancer.

Comment: Is it possible to install SSL in Network load balancer? And will I be able to publish via ftp?

Comment: Yes, NLB supports SSL. ftp should work, because NLB works at TCP network layer which is below FTP and HTTP.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try.

Comment: How did it go? Did NLB help?

Comment: Thanks for remembering. I haven't it yet, as I am simultaneously developing some software. Anyways I am still learning aws, and am not yet sure how to use NLB. Thanks a lot.